# zip function in python

Tags: python

In python I have:

```
    nameh.append([area, hitratio])
    nameh_sorted = sorted (nameh, key=lambda nameh: nameh[0])
```

I sorted the [area, hitratio] based on the alphabet of the name of the area. Then I want to zip the sorted "hitratio" with another list "u" into [u1, hitratio1], [u2, hitratio2]...but I don't know how to select the sorted hitratio in this case, the *nameh_sorted[1] is obviously wrong...

```
user = zip (u,*nameh_sorted[1])
user_sorted = sorted (user, key=lambda user: user[0])
x5, y5 = zip(*user_sorted)
```

Can anyone help? Many thanks

Comment: You don't need to provide a key function in this case -- the default is to sort lexicographically, so the first element is the primary search key by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
user = zip(u, (hitratio for area, hitratio in nameh_sorted))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
user = zip(u, [x[1] for x in nameh_sorted])
```

Is that what you want?